# How to convert hex to ASCII

Tags: arduino-uno

I am receiving bytes, converting them into hex and now I need to convert the hex to ASCII. Can it be done on an Arduino? Or do I need something else? 
I am new to programming with Arduino.

Comment: Is this connected to your earlier question? It is not clear, what you mean. In your previous code you are explicitly sending an ASCII version of hex (human readable hex).

Comment: i am receiving bytes and then converting them into hex or displaying them as hex ,and now i want to display them as ascii , is that possible ? sorry for this maybe dumb questions but i want to learn.

Comment: Can you show your (relevant) code, the location where you want to convert it, and describe how the output should look like?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a byte variable `b`, you can

- `write(b)` it as it is. if it is ASCII code of a readable character, the Serial Monitor will display it as that character, for example for 65 it will printt 'A'
- print it as decimal number with `print(b)`. for 65 it will print "65"
- print it as hexadecimal number with `print(b, HEX)`. for 65 it will print "41"
- print it as a number in other base with `print(b, base)`, for example `print(b, 2)` will print 1000001 if b is 65 in decimal